# Using pointers as counters in C language

Tags: c

So here's the edited code!!
I am a beginner to C language and I am having problems in printing this pattern. With a request for 3 lines, I should get

```
*
**
***
```

I am using pointers as counters.  Please help me out.  My code is not working properly..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
   {
  int *a=NULL,*b=NULL,*n=NULL;
  n= malloc (sizeof *n);
  printf("Enter the lines\n");
  scanf("%d",n);
  a= malloc (sizeof *a);
  b= malloc (sizeof *b);
  for (*a=0; *a<*n; *(a)++)
    {
        for (*b=0; *b<=*a; *(b)++)
                printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
 free(n);
 free(a);
 free(b);
 return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Replace `&*n` with `n`, replace `*0` with `0` (that's a new one, lol), and tell us what the acutal problem or error is.

Comment: System after return does not make sense. Also: why malloc when you can just declare int a,b,n? Is that for learning purpose?

Comment: as i mentioned earlier, i am a beginner to C language and i would be very thankful for your help :)
And yes, its just for the sake of learning :)

Comment: I know I suggested to edit the question with updated code, but it would have been helpful to leave the original question as it was and add in the 'new' code as an update afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

The obvious errors are in expressions like `*a++`. The operator precedence makes the compiler to interpret it as `*(a++)`, i.e. it increments the pointer, not the counter. What you need in this case is actually `(*a)++`. You have to use parentheses explicitly to make such expressions work they way you want them to work. It looks like you generated this code by using mindless textual substitution of local varibles `a`, `b` and `n` with their dynamically allocated equivalents `*a`, `*b` and `*n`, but completely forgot to pay attention to operator precedence.

In any case, you are not using "pointers as counters" here, as you seem to incorrectly believe. You are using `int` objects as counters. But instead of declaring these `int` objects as ordinary local variables, you decided to allocate them dynamically. This makes no practical sense is this simplistic code, but is probably worth something as an excercise.

As it has already been noted in the comments, unary `&` and unary `*` "annihilate" each other, meaning that your `&*n` (although not an error) is equivalent to a plain `n`. Also, what is `*0` supposed to mean? It won't even compile. You correctly assigned your `*a` as `*a = 0`. Why did you suddently decide to assign your `*b` as `*b = *0`??? Where did that extra `*` come from?

And finally, drop the strange habit of casting the result of `malloc`. This is what your `malloc`s should look like

```
a = malloc(sizeof *a);
```

Comment: This the code after correction, but still its not working properly!
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int *a=NULL,*b=NULL,*n=NULL;
 n= malloc (sizeof *n);
 printf("Enter the lines\n");
 scanf("%d",n);
 a= malloc (sizeof *a);
 b= malloc (sizeof *b);
 for (*a=0; *a<*n; *(a)++)
  {
   for (*b=0; *b<=*a; *(b)++)
     printf("*");
   printf("\n");
  }
 free(n);
 free(a);
 free(b);
 return 0;
}

Comment: @user3037348, you can edit your question with the updated code. Writing it in the comments makes it hard to read.

Comment: @user3037348: You have to pay attention. Not `*(a)++`, but `(*a)++`. Do you notice the difference? It it looks like you are mechanically changing the code without understanding what you are doing. Maybe you should read a book on the language first.

Comment: In `*(a)++` the parentheses achieves absolutely nothing, i.e. `*(a)++` is the same as your original `*a++`. It should be specifically `(*a)++`. You have to force grouping between `*` and `a`.